# Is it possible to receive $_GET from multiple pages?

Tags: php, http

I just want to know if it's possible to receive variables through $_GET from multiple pages. 
Is $_GET a global variable?

Comment: If you were passing the variables from page to page in a stream of redirects, I suppose it would be.

Comment: Why you would not use php session?

Comment: Can you explain your question elaborately?

Comment: Do you want to achive different page with single action page (where you will retrive the value using $_GET method). Example you have add, edit, view pages but all the action goes to single page.. am I right?

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp

The $_GET variable comes from URI parameters passed in the address bar. There will be one $_GET variable per request and they do not have to be the same from request to request. They don't persist from page to page unless you set them again purposely. However it is a global variable and may be used in different PHP files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes $_GET is a superglobal. It accesses the data from address bar so yes you can get data from any page when that is redirected to your page with query string data.